# Proving set equality using Kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:G->A$ be a homomorphism with kernel H and let $a \in G$. Prove that the set equality $\{x \in G | f(x)=f(a)\}=Ha$

My opinion:

$(\subseteq)$ Let $x \in G$ st. $f(x)=f(a)$. Then $f(x)f^{-1}(a)=e_{A} => f(x)f^{-1}(a) \in Kerf=H$. Then $f(x)f(a^{-1})=f(xa^{-1})=h_{0}$ for some $h_{0} \in H$. Then $xa^{-1}=f^{-1}(h_{0})$ and so $x=f^{-1}(h_{0})a$. Since $f^{-1}(h_{0}) \in H$(i am not sure about this), $x \in Ha$. Therefore, $\{x \in G | f(x)=f(a)\}\subseteq Ha$.

And I wasn't able to show the converse..

Comment: I think the idea is essentially correct, but the notation isn't quite right (using $f^{-1}(b)$, which denotes a preimage, rather than $f(b)^{-1}$, which denote the inverse of an element). I'd start with:

"Pick $x \in G$ such that $f(x) = f(a)$; multiplying both sides on the left by $f(a)^{-1}$ gives $e_A = f(x) f(a)^{-1} = f(x) f(a^{-1}) = f(x a^{-1})$. Equivalently, $x a^{-1} \in \ker f = H$ and hence $x \in Ha$..."

Comment: I understand the mistake of the notation, thank you. How can I start with the second part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converse is easier:

($\supseteq$) If $x\in Ha$, then $x = ha$ for some $h\in H$, so $f(x) = f(ha) = f(h)f(a) = f(a)$.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome.